# How many possible solutions could the system $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ have . . .?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A$ be a $4 \times 3$ matrix and let $\mathbf{b}  \in \mathbb{R}^4$. How many solutions could the system $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ have if $N (A) = \{ \mathbf{0} \}$? Answer the same question if $N(A) \neq \{ \mathbf{0} \}$. Explain your answers.

My Attempt:

**
If the nullspace of $A$ is trivial, then the echelon form of the coefficient matrix $A$, and hence the echelon form of the augmented matrix $[ A | \mathbf{b} ]$, of the given system  have the full three pivots. Hence the reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix will be of the form
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & c_1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & c_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & c_3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_4 \end{matrix} \right].
$$
So if $N(A) = \{ \mathbf{0} \}$, then the given system has no soluion (if $c_4 \neq 0$) or a unique solution (if $c_4 = 0$).

On the other hand, if $N(A) \neq \{ \mathbf{0} \}$, then the reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix will be a matrix of the form
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & t_1 & t_2 & c_1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_4 \end{matrix} \right]
$$
or
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & t_1 & c_1 \\ 0 & 1 & t_2  & c_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_4 \end{matrix} \right]
$$
In either case our system has either no solution or infinitely many solutions.
**

Is my reasoning correct? If so, have I managed to arrive at the right conclusions as well in both cases? Or, are there any problems?

Comment: One minor oversight is that when the rank of $\ A\ $is $2$, the second column of the unit matrix might be the *third* column of your reduced echelon form rather than the second.   Your conclusions are still valid for that case also, however, and are correct.